# Type hinting with doctrine: Is the type attribute still required on @ORM\Column annotation when using PHP 7.4 with type hints?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, type-hinting, php-7.4

The doctrine documentation for [@ORM\Column](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_column) says that the type-attribute is required. Does that still hold with PHP 7.4? With type hints directly in PHP I feel that the type-attribute in the annotation is redundant. Is there a way to not provide the type-attribute and make doctrine infer it from the PHP type hints?

**Example:**

Instead of using this code

```
class Client
{
    /** @ORM\Column(name="code"   , type="string" , length=20    , unique=true) */ private string $code;
    /** @ORM\Column(name="moduleX", type="boolean", nullable=true             ) */ private ?bool $moduleX;
    // [...]
```

I'd like to write the following:

```
class Client
{
    /** @ORM\Column(name="code"   , length=20, unique=true) */ private string $code;
    /** @ORM\Column(name="moduleX",                       ) */ private ?bool $moduleX;
    // [...]
```

If not, is that feature in discussion - or is there a way to suggest it?

Comment: The current version of Doctrine (2.7) runs on PHP 7.1 so no, it has no idea about typed properties.  You can check the github site and see what the plans are for Doctrine 3.  I have not been keeping track but I suspect 7.4 is not being targeted and thus no typed properties.  But I could be wrong.

Comment: It could also take the name from the property but its not the point. Also there are more types that correspond to string/float/integer in doctrine types so it would still have to be conditional or a default pick. ORM is a mapper and this in one of the places this mapping is defined.

Comment: The upcoming Doctrine version (3.0) is based on PHP 7.2+. But that doesn not mean it has to ignore the possibilities PHP 7.4 provides - it could also work well with infering types when available, so the "based on PHP 7.2+" property doesn't really help here in my opinion.

Comment: Btw _"It could also take the name from the property"_ does already work.

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine types is [conversion between PHP and SQL types](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types). Even simple PHP types like `string` can be VARCHAR, DECIMAL, or CLOB in the database.

And the type hint can be an object too:

```php
private UuidInterface $id;
```

How to store this in the database? String, binary, integer?

Doctrine doesn't know about your application business logic so I think reflection is not a good replacement for annotation.

Comment: Did not actually answer the question.  More importantly, Doctrine has it's own typing mapping system and generally picks reasonable defaults.  For example, a very common Doctrine attribute is 'string'.  Somehow, Doctrine manages to work fine even if you don't provide more detailed requirements.  And when Doctrine does eventually support typed properties, it will be smart enough to map something like UuidInterface to a guid a column.

Comment: But type also require several methods. Continue with Uuid:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html#custom-mapping-types and https://github.com/ramsey/uuid-doctrine/blob/master/src/UuidType.php

Comment: You are not wrong with what you say. Nevertheless defaulting where possible is a very good (and already implemented) thing. Following along that line, it would be very helpful to infer types like int, bool and especially nullable="true" via ?int and ?bool. For classes, inference is more difficult, I give you that, but int and bool are very, very common types, so that would cover a big portion of the code.